# Enumerating $k$-permutations

Tags: combinatorics

One can use the [Lehmer code for enumerating permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_in_computing) where all items of a group are used.

Is there a similar code, or way of using the Lehmer code, for enumerating k-permutations $P^n_k = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ where only k items of a group are chosen?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for simplicity the objects you are enumerating are natural numbers, you can first generate the set of permutations of $[k]$, call it $P_k$ using the Lehmer algorithm, and then for every subset S of size $k$ of the original set, choose any bijection from $[k]$ to $S$, and apply the bijection to every permutation in $P_k$.

One might think that this is overly complicated, but it is quite easy to create a bijection from $S$ to some given $[k]$, simply order the elements of $S$ and send each element to its index with this ordering